# Select with 5 tables creating almost duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

I have a database where I have to get name of the review where is the relevant comment and I also need to get the username of person who made that comment.

In order to do that, I have to go through 5 tables because there is no direct connection from comments table`jamacomments` to review table `review`.

I can get review name by:

- joining table `revision_user` with jamacomments
- then joining revision_user table with user table `userbase`
- then joining revision_user table with revision table `revision` which is just updated review
- then joining revision table with review table `review`

My sql query:

```
select jamacomment.id, jamacomment.userId, jamacomment.commentText,
userbase.id, userbase.userName,
revision_user.userId, revision_user.revisionId,
revision.id, revision.reviewId, review.id, review.name
from jamacomment

left join revision_user
on jamacomment.userId=revision_user.userId
left join userbase
on revision_user.userId=userbase.id
left join revision
on revision_user.revisionId=revision.id
left join review
on revision.reviewId=review.id

group by jamacomment.id
```

To maybe clarify some things more clearly:

- jamacomment.userId is foreign key userbase.id
- revision_user.userId is foreign key to userbase.id ( so it's the same as jamacomment.userId)
- revision_user.revisionId is foreign key to revision.id
- revision.reviewId is foreign key to review.id

So I can get from jamacomment to revision_user from that to revision and from revision to review.

It leaves me with too many records, where it duplicates some data, but not fully. It is a duplicate to certain point where it gives random revisionId number and the rest of the data is wrong by that too.

By using `group by` I'm selecting only unique jamacomment.id because there can only be so many rows as there are comments. But It retrieves me with wrong records as I wanted to get. It shows some correct lines, but some with data wich is not that comment data, but different comment data.

Maybe I have incorrect select or some wrong left join or I should use other type of join, anyway, I could use any help, to get the correct data to each comment.

---

Adding dummy table with data for better understanding

```
table 'userbase'    table 'jamacomment'  
id  | userName      id  | userId  | commentText

1   | Peter         1   | 2       | First comment review1
2   | Jack          2   | 2       | Second comment review1
3   | Ann           3   | 1       | Comment in first review
                    4   | 1       | Comment in second review
                    5   | 1       | Comm in 2nd review 2nd revision
                    6   | 3       | Comment in review1 2nd revision


table 'revision_user'      table 'revision'                  table 'review'
userId  | revisionId       id  | reviewId  | sequence        id  | name

2  | 1                     1   | 1         | 1               1   | review1
2  | 1                     2   | 2         | 1               2   | review2
1  | 1                     3   | 1         | 2   
1  | 2                     4   | 2         | 2
1  | 4
3  | 3
```

---

Expected result should be:

```
table 'jamacomment'                        'userbase'   'revision_user'   'revision'           'review'
id|userId |commentText                     |id |userName |userId |revisionId |id |reviewId |sequence|id|name

1 |2      |First comment review1           |2  |Jack     |2      |1          |1  |1        |1       |1 |review1  
2 |2      |Second comment review1          |2  |Jack     |2      |1          |1  |1        |1       |1 |review1
3 |1      |Comment in first review         |1  |Peter    |1      |1          |1  |1        |1       |1 |review1
4 |1      |Comment in second review        |1  |Peter    |1      |2          |2  |2        |1       |2 |review2
5 |1      |Comm in 2nd review 2nd revision |1  |Peter    |1      |4          |4  |2        |4       |2 |review2
6 |3      |Comment in review1 2nd revision |3  |Ann      |3      |3          |3  |1        |2       |1 |review1
```

---

Forgot to add info that It supposedly breaks somewhere at revisionId where it makes duplicates of the  data to revisionId but in revisionId changes the id to those lines. It adds 3 duplicates to each item. The rest info refers to the incorrect revisionId. I suppose It's 3 duplicates because I have 3 reviews or 3 revisions for one review.

It shows me 128 records without group by. with group by it shows the correct 36 records, but It gets some correct and some incorrect records.

Comment: You are using GROUP BY without a aggegrate functions, which is incorrect use of GROUP BY. Can you post expected result?

Comment: Added expected result

Comment: You should reconsider your data structure, no there's a many to many relation between jamacomment and revision_user (on user_id)

Comment: I know that there is a relation between jamacomment and revision_user and thats the only way to get through to review.name. Unfortunately It's not my database, It's database of system we are using for project management which we didn't create ourselves. So there is no way to recreate data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Left join will populate your result try using inner join if you want to get only the matches record found on the table that you are joining.

Comment: I already tried to use inner join and right join and even full join. Those produce worse results

Comment: Can you provide some dummy table and data for visualization.

Comment: Added tables with dummy data and additional sequence column for revison table which maybe could help